# SQL query for retrieving packages for adult and child combination

Tags: sql

```
create table hotelSupplier
(
        prod_id int,
        sku_id bigint,
        activity_name nvarchar(20),
        package nvarchar(20),
        adult binary(1),
        child binary(1),
        validation_date date,
        launch_date date,
        city nvarchar(10),
        est_units_per_day int
)
```

I have to write a query for retrieving those prod_id, packages from table where supplier give me the result based on city, validation date and no of adults and child. I have tried to solve it, but I am stuck in the case of no. of adults and child case as supplier don't have no. of adults and child column. It needs to check first whether the particular sku_id is set or unset for adult or child.Then it has to be compared with estimated units per day, if available then it has to be printed.

```
alter procedure uspGetKlookDetails 
    @city nvarchar(10),
    @valid_date date,
    @no_of_adults int,
    @no_of_child int,
    @age int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM hotelSupplier 
    WHERE city = @city 
      AND validation_date < @valid_date
      AND est_units_per_day >= CASE
                                  WHEN adult = 1 THEN @no_of_adults
                                  WHEN child = 1 THEN @no_of_child
                               END
END
GO
```

Comment: tag the relevant database mysql/sql server. Also kindly provide input and expected output sample. What exactly is the question here ?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Your code looks like SQL Server/T-SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Because adult and child are binary then they can only be either 0 or 1, so by grouping by for ex. prod_id which is one of the things you want, and then you use sum() (if your sql platform allows for this unknown which sql you use) you can get how many adults and children there are:

```
select prod_id, sku_id, activity_name, package, 
sum(adult) as nrofadults, sum(child) as nrofchildren, 
validation_date, launch_date, city, est_units_per_day 
from hotelSupplier
group by prod_id
```